# Toggle Button Not Working Properly on Bluetooth Adapter

Tags: android, toggle, android-bluetooth

Hi Sir/Ma'am,
                    I'm trying to Enable/Disable Bluetooth on Toggle Button and also there is an additional functionality which ask for password on enable/disable. Toggle Button is taking default state of Bluetooth at launch(Means if Bluetooth is Enable, then toggle will be set on  and if Bluetooth is Disable, toggle will be off).

Also, its working fine on when we enter correct password. But, the main problem is that When I enter wrong password, Toggle is not behave as expected.

What I mean, Suppose Bluetooth is On and I am trying to disable it by my app. When I click on Toggle, it ask me to enter password. Now, If i enter wrong password, Bluetooth doesn't turn off, but toggle button changed its state to turn Off.

Here is What I tried so far:-

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mb = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    tb1 = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.appToggleBtn);

    tb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Check();
        }
    });
}


 public void Check()
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    dialog.show();

    ImageView saveBtn=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirmdialogBtn);
    final EditText password=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirmdialogEditText);

     saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(password.getText().toString().equals("asd"))
            {
                if(mb.isEnabled())
                {
                    mb.disable();
                    tb1.setChecked(mb.isEnabled());
                }
                else
                {
                    mb.enable();
                    tb1.setChecked(mb.isEnabled());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong", 1000).show();  
                if(mb.isEnabled())
                {
                    tb1.setChecked(mb.isEnabled());
                }
                else
                {
                    tb1.setChecked(mb.isEnabled());
                }
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

     });

}
```

Also,  for Toggle Button, I used:-

```
  android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
```

and in toggle_selector.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
```

Please Please Help me into this. I am badly stuck at this point.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not **[cross-post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/284009/22815)**. Please read: **[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/255171)**

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
            if(password.getText().toString().equals("asd"))
            { 
                if(mb.isEnabled()) 
                { 
                    mb.disable(); 
                    tb1.setChecked(mb.isEnabled()); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    mb.enable(); 
                    tb1.setChecked(mb.isEnabled()); 
                } 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong", 1000).show();
            }
```